# updating a count depending on values in a file fulfilling criteria specified by a second file

Tags: awk

I have two files and I want to update file A with a new column containing counts of how many times the number in $2 of file B fell with the range of $2 and  $3 of file A, but only when $1 matches in both files.

**file A**

```
n01 2000 9000
n01 29000 41000
n01 60000 89000
n05 10000 15000
n80 5000 12000
n80 59000 68000
n80 100000 110000
```

**file B**

```
n01 6000
n01 6800
n01 35000
n05 14000
n80 65000
n80 104000
```

**expected output**

```
n01 2000 9000 2
n01 29000 41000 1 
n01 60000 89000 0
n05 10000 15000 1
n80 5000 12000 0
n80 59000 68000 1
n80 100000 110000 1
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you having any specific problems?

Comment: I agree with @TomFenech . Voting to close as "too broad", as there can be many ways to do this. Showing your attempts would be best for all of us: we would be able to assist on where you are stuck and you will more likely get some answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  awk '
  FNR==NR{
              A[$1,$2]
              next
         }
         {
           c = 0
           for(i in A)
           {
              split(i,X,SUBSEP)
              if(X[1] == $1)
              {
                if(X[2] >= $2 && X[2] <= $3)
                {
                    c++
                }
              }
           }
           print $0,c
        }
       ' fileB fileA
```

Comment: Some explanation would be useful. Also, you might want to consider writing an awk script and running it using `awk -f script.awk fileB fileA` rather than using a "one-liner".

Comment: You can if you want. It would make your answer better.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly strict awk, but you can help your script with some bash utils like this:

```
join fileA fileB -a1 | awk '{ key=$1 " " $2 " " $3; if (! (key in array) ){array[key]=0} } $4>=$2 && $4<=$3{key=$1 " " $2 " " $3; array[key]=array[key] + 1;  }END{ for(val in array){print val" "array[val]} }' | sort -n
```

First join both files with the join command. Then create an array in AWK and sum 1 each time that the desired condition fulfills. Finally, you may want to sort your output to get elements sorted by the key.